# How to pass variables in mutation graphQL Playground?

Tags: node.js, graphql, mutation

I am using apollo express server 2.0. And I am trying to execute mutation in the graphql playground. Here is the mutation I have attached a screenshot with another screenshot of a variable.

[image: Mutation Command to create new user]
[image: Mutation variables]

I am getting the following error when I am trying to execute mutation command in the graphql playground.

[image]

Please guide me where I am incorrect.

Comment: Remove the id in the mutation or add it in the vars.  Also, remove the mname in your input.  GraphQL error messages all mean the same thing - "Something is wrong, good luck!"  You may have to change your resolver param also but you didn't post the resolver, which should always be done with GraphQL.  I've seen that message many times...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are two tabs `QUERY VARIABLES` and `HTTP HEADERS` in the input field at the bottom right of graphQL Playground.
Please check the tab `QUERY VARIABLES` is selected.

Answer (score -1):

Seems you have to define each of the input fields separately.